# Get Individual results of Mongodb Average of Two columns

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a dataset like t

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a867bae000e4f1c9c77d36d"),
    "userid" : "5a20ee1acdacc7086ce7742d",
    "sprice" : null,
    "lprice" : 4.2,
    "fruit" : "@Apple",
    "createdate" : ISODate("2018-02-16T06:35:26.285Z"),
    "__v" : 0
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a867bae000e4f1c9c77d36e"),
    "userid" : "5a20ee1acdacc7086ce7742e",
    "sprice" : 3.5,
    "lprice" : null,
    "fruit" : "@Apple",
    "createdate" : ISODate("2018-02-16T06:35:26.285Z"),
    "__v" : 0
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a867bae000e4f1c9c77d36e"),
    "userid" : "5a20ee1acdacc7086ce7742e",
    "sprice" : 8.6,
    "lprice" : 2.2,
    "fruit" : "@Apple",
    "createdate" : ISODate("2018-02-16T06:35:26.285Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

for this I have to calculate the Average sprice of '@Apple' and neglect those entry which have value NULL.

For this My query is like this which returns exactly what I want, i.e

```
db.Collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "fruit": "@Apple",
        "sprice": {$ne:null}
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "sprice": { "$avg": "$sprice" }
    }}
])
```

It gives me the result. Now my Question is If I want to get the Individual Result of sprice and lprice then How My query is modified.

Expected answer will be like this:

```
{ "_id" : null, "sprice" : 6.05 } // Already Get from this query
{ "_id" : null, "lprice" : 3.2 } //Desired Result.
```

Any Help is Appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With **[`$facet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/)**

```
db.Collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "fruit": "@Apple" } },
    {
        "$facet": {
            "sprice": [
                { "$match": { "sprice": { "$ne": null } } },
                { "$group": {
                    "_id": null,
                    "sprice": { "$avg": "$sprice" }
                }}
            ],   
            "lprice": [
                { "$match": { "lprice": { "$ne": null } } },                
                { "$group": {
                    "_id": null,
                    "lprice": { "$avg": "$lprice" }
                }}
            ]
        }
    }
])
```

**Sample Output**

```
[
    { "sprice": { "_id" : null, "sprice" : 6.05 } },
    { "lprice": { "_id" : null, "lprice" : 3.2 } }
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for suggesting the Good And efficient way. Really Appreciate you man

Answer (score 0):

`$avg` ignores non numeric values by default so no explicit null filter is required, below pipeline will give you the desired results

```
db.Collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "fruit": "@Apple"        
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "sprice": { "$avg": "$sprice" },
        "lprice": { "$avg": "$lprice" }
    }}       
])
```